# How to validate dropdown data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I am facing one problem. Firstly Look at photo
[image]

Here are working hours when user click on checkbox dropdown will be active this is working fine. I want when user click on Checkbox of Like Tuesday now dropdown will be active But user have not Select any time from both the dropdown and i want alert or something error message you have not select the  time of tuesday.

Here is my htmlcode:-

```
enter code here
<div class="form-group">
<label class="add-info">WORKING HOURS:</label>
<div>
    <div class="info_user_detail">
        <table class="table_info1">
        @foreach($days as $key=> $alldays)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox no-margin">
                        <label>
                        <input name="days[]" value="{{ $alldays }}"type="checkbox">{{ $alldays }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="time-class">
                       <select name="from[]"class="select-class from">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            @foreach($from as $froms)
                            <option>{{ $froms }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="time-class">
                       <select name="to[]"class="select-class to">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And My Jquery Code:-

```
enter code here
  $(".time-class .from").attr("disabled",true);
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function () {
     if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).parents('td:first').next().find('.from').attr("disabled",false);
     }
});
$(".from").on('change',function(){
    var value= $(this).val();
    var elem=$(this);
    elem.parents('td:first').find('.loader').show();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers:
        {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:'hours',
        data:{
            value:value
        },
        type:"post",
        success:function(resp)
        {
            if($.trim(resp))
            {
                elem.parents('td:first').find('.loader').hide();
                elem.parents('td:first').next().find('.to').html(resp);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My Laravel Function:-

```
enter code here
public function hours(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        $data = $request->all();
        $to = array("7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24"); 
        $newdata = "";
        $newdata .= '<option  value="">Select</option>';
        if(!empty($data['value'])){
            foreach($to as $tos)
            {
                if($tos > $data['value']){
                    $tos1 = $tos >= 12 ? ":00 PM" : ":00 AM" ;
                 $newdata .= '<option  value="'.$tos.'">'.$tos.' '. $tos1.' </option>';
                }
            }
        }
        echo $newdata;die;
    }
}
```

I am using Laravel framwork.Please help me. Thanks in adavance :)

Comment: When do you want this error to be shown: "i want alert or something error message you have not select the time of tuesday." In other words, what would trigger this?

Comment: I want when user submit the form without selecting time

Comment: if user click the checkbox of tuesday but not select the time from dropdown and i want alert message in that case and viceversa for others

Comment: I would suggest starting with the basics of DOM manipulation. Apparently Javascript is what is going to be used to achieve what you are after. In order to avoid complicated selectors , it would be wise to assign IDs to each one of the <select> and <input> you have so that you are able to easily access their values. Then you also need to apply EventListeners to your CheckBoxes "https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events#registering-events-and-listeners" in order when a user clicks on a CheckBox you can check if Dates and Times are filled and create a Warning accordingly.